# use column-name range in data.table like in dplyrs select

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I would like to select multiple columns from a data.table (with 1200 column-names) specifying a range by column-name, like one can do with dplyr, for example:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dt <- data.table(w = sample(100, 50),
       x = sample(100, 50),
       y = sample(100, 50),
       z = sample(100, 50))

select(dt, w:y)
```

Currently I am using the following work-around:

```
cols_to_select <- names(select(dt, w:y))
dt[ ,cols_to_select, with = FALSE]
```

I think the other option of using the col-numbers (for example `dt[ , 1:3, with = FALSE]` could lead to nasty bugs.
Another option to select the names would be:

```
dt[ , .SD, .SDcols = cols_to_select]
```

It would be super-awesome if there was something like the following:

```
dt[ , .(w:y)]
```

Is there a better way to do this? And if not why? If this question is better placed at the github-issues of data.table let me know

Comment: `select_vars(names(dt), w:y)` is probably better than `names(select(dt, w:y))`

Comment: why? because you have more options?

Comment: Isn't that already there in the development version?

Comment: `dt[, w:y, with=FALSE]` should work with 1.9.5..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I asked for is possible in the development-version of data.table (1.9.5) as can be seen in the [new feature](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) number 17. quoting:

> 17. .SDcols  and  with=FALSE  understand  colA:colB  form now. That is,  DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=V1, .SDcols=V4:V6]  and  DT[, V5:V7,
>       with=FALSE]  works as intended. This is quite useful for interactive
>       use. Closes #748.

the installation of the development-version is explained [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Thanks for pointing this out @AnandaMahto and @Arun!

also using `select_vars(names(dt), w:y)` from dplyr is probably better than `names(select(dt, w:y))` as pointed out by @shadow, because it gives more options to select the names, is more readable and conveys the intent more clearly.

Comment: Arun--one of the `data.table` developers, not akrun :-)

Comment: thanks :) :D, at least I knew that he is one of the data.table-developers ^^